# VC++ libcurl .lib size

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, libcurl

I'm having an issue with the size of the .lib when I compile libcurl. It's 1.6 MB and the sample program they have is alround 300 KB.

I downloaded the latest version (curl-7.20.0) and opened the project file from the lib directory in visual studio 2008. In the project properties I set /MT and compiled a release build. I even tried adding HTTP_ONLY to the processor which didn't seem to affect anything. What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn off Whole Program Optimization to keep the size reasonable.  Project + Properties, C/C++, Optimization.

Comment: I don't repro, getting a 700KB libcurl.lib by opening the .dsw file, converting it and setting /MT.  You'll need to explain why you think the size is wrong.